# Can I use atmega328P without capacitors?

Tags: atmega328

I need to use atmega328P without arduino board, so far I know that I will need `16MHZ Quartz Resonator` and two `22nf capacitors`. However, I have seen that other people are using atmega328P without capacitors.

What is the role of those capacitors? Can I use atmega328P without capacitors?

Comment: You need 22pF (picofarad) capacitors, not 22nF.

Comment: You also need power supply bypass capacitors.

Comment: you can use it without caps and with a crystal, at half speed, but maybe half price too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those specific capacitors form part of the resonant clock oscillator circuit. If you are using a quartz crystal then they are required. You can't do without them.

If you use a 16MHz *ceramic resonator*, however, they don't need the capacitors (they're built into the resonator).

Also, if you have your ATMega328P on a breadboard the capacitance of the board itself is sometimes enough to "get it working", though as soon as you transfer your circuit to a permanent PCB it will suddenly stop working for no apparent reason.

Comment: One could also use the build-in 8MHz RC oscillator, and remove the crystal entirely.

Comment: @Gerben Indeed. Or use an external clock source, like a MEMS oscillator.